# A 8192-dimensional VLAD vector take 32KB of of memory per image. How?

Tags: dimension, vlad-vector

I have a simple question concerning VLAD vector representation. How is it that an 8192-dimensional (k=64, 128-D SIFT) VLAD vector take '32KB of of memory' per image? I could not relate these two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [VLFeat documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/vlad-fundamentals.html), each element of the VLAD vector is given by

[image: v_k = sum_i q_ik (x_i - mu_i)]

where `x_i` is a descriptor vector (here: a 128-dimensional SIFT vector), and `u_k` is the center of the `k`th cluster - i.e. also a 128-dimensional SIFT vector. `q_ik` denotes the strength of association between `x_i` and `u_i`, which is 0 or 1 if K-means clustering is used. Thus, each `v_k` is 128-dimensional.

The VLAD vector of an image `I` is then given by stacking all `v_k`:

[image: Vlad vector]

This vector has `k` elements, and each element is 128-dimensional.
Thus, for `k=64`, we end up with `64 * 128 = 8192` numbers describing image `I`.

Finally, if we use floating point numbers for each element, each number requires 4 bytes of memory. We thus end up with a total memory usage of `64 * 128 * 4 = 32768` Bytes or 32KB for the VLAD vector of each image.